# How to demo your react-native app continuously during development

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, demo

As the title suggest I need to be able to showcase a react native app continuously during development every other day with a client which is not technical orientated. The alternativs I see is,

```
 * Sharing a git/github repo for them to download and run through Xcode 
 which is not a possibility.

 *Screen record while i run the simulation on my computer and share it 
 with the client
```

Both of these options seems subpar and not optimal.

*How do I do this in a better way?*

I am sorry if this seems like an open ended question and if you have suggestions on how to better formulate this question please provide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the binary to [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/), which allows your client to download and use the app instantly.

You can also consider over-the-air update systems like [Expo](http://expo.io/) or [CodePush](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push) which allows you to deliver Javascript-only updates automatically to your clients when they open the app (just like a web app).

Comment: Thank you I will check those options out!